# proxy_pass overwrites the URL changed by rewrite directive

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxypass

From the nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) as quoted below, I understand that `proxy_pass` directive will not the change the URI and will just pass the rewritten URI to the server.

> - When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break):
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/randomstring;
>   }
>   ```
>
>   In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

But when I set the `proxy_pass` to a variable, the URI is being overwritten.

Example:

```
location /test_rewrite {
    set $ups_addr http://upstream_server;
    rewrite /test_rewrite /test_rewrite_upstream break;
    proxy_pass $ups_addr/random_string;
}
```

The URI `/test_rewrite` is being rewritten to `/random_string`.

Can anyone help me understand the reason for this behavior?

Comment: @Brucelet Are you sure you don't delete my quotations by mistake? I marked a citation from nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) (link to which I also included with my edit) in order to separate it from OP's text.

Comment: Oh that's my bad. Was going through the review queue and it looked a little mangled so I tried to clean it up, but I didn't fully realize the context. Reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the same documentation states below:

> - When variables are used in proxy_pass:
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri;
>   }
>   ```
>
>   In this case, if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI.

This is true only if resulting string contains an URI part. Some examples:

```
location /test_rewrite {
    set $ups_addr http://upstream_server;
    rewrite /test_rewrite /test_rewrite_upstream break;
    proxy_pass $ups_addr;
}
```

Resulting string does not contain an URI part, URI passed to upstream server is `/test_rewrite_upstream`.

```
location /test_rewrite {
    set $ups_addr http://upstream_server/;
    rewrite /test_rewrite /test_rewrite_upstream break;
    proxy_pass $ups_addr;
}
```

Resulting string contains an URI part (note the trailing slash at the end of `$ups_addr` variable), URI passed to upstream server is `/`.

You can use an `$uri` variable to combine rewrite rules with the custom URI parts in a `proxy_pass` directive:

```
location /test_rewrite {
    set $ups_addr http://upstream_server;
    rewrite /test_rewrite /test_rewrite_upstream break;
    proxy_pass $ups_addr/random_string$uri;
}
```

In this case URI passed to upstream server is `/random_string/test_rewrite_upstream`.

To preserve request arguments, use the [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) and [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) variables:

```
location /test_rewrite {
    set $ups_addr http://upstream_server;
    rewrite /test_rewrite /test_rewrite_upstream break;
    proxy_pass $ups_addr$uri$is_args$args;
}
```