# Nginx - Reverse proxy everything after location specification

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx to reverse proxy a specific location specification, as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /example {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/test;
    }
}
```

Now, when I try and access a resource at `http://example.com/example/css/styles.css` I expect it to try and access `http://localhost:8080/test/css/styles.css`. But alas - I get a 404 from nginx.

When I try and access `http://example.com/example` it shows me what's on `http://localhost:8080/test` (so I know the base url segment is working) minus anything being imported into that page from a relative url (e.g. styles and JS files)

How do I get the reverse proxy to work with child url segments?

Comment: Add slashes at the end of `location` and `proxy_pass` parameters.

Comment: @IvanShatsky that seems to work, thank you!

Comment: You can find more info about `proxy_pass` befavior related to slashes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084239/proxy-pass-overwrites-the-url-changed-by-rewrite-directive/) is my detailed explanation of some `proxy_pass` behavior aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Per Ivan's comment on the original question, here is a working configuration with trailing slashes added:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /example/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/test/;
    }
}
```