# NGINX Slug directory rewrite

Tags: nginx, redirect, server, configuration, url-rewriting

Below config works with -

1. https://example.com/blog/blog/blog-slug
2. https://example.com/blog/blog-slug

I want to make it work only with the second option

https://example.com/blog/blog-slug

```
location /blog/ {
    rewrite ^/blog(/?.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://1.10.4.204/;
}
```

Please guide me on how to fix it.

Comment: Use [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `rewrite ^/blog(/(?!blog/).*) $1 break;`

Comment: Not working the same issue.

Comment: do I need to make changes on location level?  

location /blog/

Comment: Indeed, you faced two different nginx mechanisms overlap. An interesting one! My `rewrite` rule works as expected, transforming `/blog/blog-slug` URI to `/blog-slug` but leaves `/blog/blog/blog-slug` URI untouched. However since you are using `proxy_pass` directive with a trailing slash, `/blog/` URI prefix, if still being present after the rewrite, will be stripped off and replaced with a single slash due to the `/blog/` argument of `location` directive, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) SO thread for details.

Comment: For some more detailed explanation see [NginX trailing slash in proxy pass url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759345/nginx-trailing-slash-in-proxy-pass-url) SO thread. The above means that generally you don't need to use that `rewrite ^/blog(/?.*)$ $1 break;` directive at all, using a prefix matching location and a trailing slash for the `proxy_pass` backend argument, `/blog` prefix can be automatically stripped from the proxied URI without an additional `rewrite` rule. Those `rewrite` rules usually used to transform original URIs in the regex matching locations.

Comment: For the detailed expanation on `proxy_pass` directive behavior and the rules it follow to choose an URI to pass for the backend, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084239/proxy-pass-overwrites-the-url-changed-by-rewrite-directive) SO thread. Now back to the question. Since you want to process `/blog/blog-slug` and `/blog/blog/blog-slug` URIs differently, final answer will depend on how do you want to process a `/blog/blog/blog-slug` request. Do you want to pass it to your `http://1.10.4.204` backend unchanged or should it be processed by some other `location` block?

Comment: thanks, @IvanShatsky backend will be unchanged. I want to work only with /blog

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. Should `/blog/blog/blog-slug` URI be passed to the same backend untouched (unlike `/blog/blog-slug` URI that should be passed as `/blog-slug`) or it shouldn't be processed by this `location` block at all?

Comment: Nginx passes as it is to the apache server. I have 2 separate machines one for Nginx and the second is apache where Wordpress is there. 

Currently, Nginx URI passes as it is to the apache server but my WordPress needs to work only with /blog, not to the /blog/blog/

Comment: Actually, when the user goes /blog/blog it should say not found 404. that is not happening.

Comment: Try `location ~ ^/blog/(?!blog/) { rewrite ^/blog(/.*) $1 break; proxy_pass http://1.10.4.204; }`. Note the absence of the trailing slash on the backend name! If you don't need to transform a `/blog/blog-slug` URI to `/blog-slug`, remove that `rewrite` directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238324/discussion-between-nilesh-mistry-and-ivan-shatsky).